# Amazon S3 bucket upload by using createPresignedPost(). Is it safe to return result to client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an api server which is calling the aws-sdk s3 function -> createPresignedPost(), then returning the result from the end point to the client which allows the client to perform the upload.

I need to know if the information which is returned is safe to return to the client or if there is any sensitive information returned here. See the fields returned below...

```
"url": "",
"key": "",
"bucket": "",
"X-Amz-Algorithm": "",
"X-Amz-Credential": "",
"X-Amz-Date": "",
"Policy": ""
"X-Amz-Signature": ""
```

Can I project any of these fields out? or are they all necessary to perform the upload?

Edit - If I remove any of the various other parameters, they each return an error similar to below
[image]

Comment: Pre-signed URLs are, ideally, designed to be shared with an authenticated client over HTTPS. They contain a bucket name, S3 object key, and the signer's access key, among other things. None of those is, per se, sensitive data but you have to make a decision for yourself, given your compliance requirements, whether or not to treat them as sensitive.

Comment: @jarmod the client is authenticated. I was mainly concerned with the fact that the X-amz-Credential parameter contains the aws access key. Would you not consider that a security risk?

Comment: No, for most people and most applications that is not a security risk. AWS would not suggest this as a solution for exactly the case in point if it were a gaping security hole. An access key is no use to you without the corresponding secret key. That said, some compliance requirements are written in a somewhat generic fashion and cannot take into account any given implementation so might restrict the visibility of such things.

Answer (score 2):

You are [pre-signing an object](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GeneratePresignedUrlAndUploadObject.java) to upload to an Amazon S3 bucket using the AWS SDK. For example, in Java, you use this:

```
  public static void signBucket(S3Presigner presigner, String bucketName, String keyName) {
try {
    PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(keyName)
            .contentType("text/plain")
            .build();

    PutObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = PutObjectPresignRequest.builder()
            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
            .putObjectRequest(objectRequest)
            .build();

    PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest = presigner.presignPutObject(presignRequest);


    String myURL = presignedRequest.url().toString();
    System.out.println("Presigned URL to upload a file to: " +myURL);
    System.out.println("Which HTTP method needs to be used when uploading a file: " +
            presignedRequest.httpRequest().method());

    // Upload content to the Amazon S3 bucket by using this URL
    URL url = presignedRequest.url();

    // Create the connection and use it to upload the new object by using the presigned URL
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/plain");
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write("This text was uploaded as an object by using a presigned URL.");
    out.close();

    connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("HTTP response code is " + connection.getResponseCode());

} catch (S3Exception e) {
    e.getStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.getStackTrace();
}
```

}

As shown in this Java example, the only value you need to return to the client is the URL. A client can use this to upload an object. Also, notice that you can also control the time that the URL is valid via the **signatureDuration** value.

Comment: The returned url only includes the url of the bucket itself. And attempting to upload to the url without the other params gives an access denied. And also asks for the various parameters. For example see edit on post